# Mining Nanopool for 24H with Radeon RX 480 and yet no shares found

Tags: mining, cpp-ethereum, mining-pools, ubuntu, genoil

I am mining with Ethminer in Nanopool for around 24h (or more) and I still didn't find any shares so my account is not yet created in Nanopool. I think this is not right.

I use the miner like this:

```
ethminer -F http://eth1.nanopool.org:8888/0xXXXXXXX -G
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this normal?

Thank you

EDIT:

I might have found the solution. As I am using Lubuntu 16.10 the AMD Property driver is not supported so I will roll back to 14.10 tonight and I will edit if I am succeed.

Comment: On a side note, don't use 14.10, use 14.4 LTS or 16.4 LTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution!

What happens is that I am using cpp-ethereum and there is an issue with this board and some drivers so I switched to the `Genoil` Fork and now is working like a charm!

You can find the `Source Code` and the `Instructions` here:

https://github.com/Genoil/cpp-ethereum

So with this `Fork` I can see my hash rate and I already made some Ether (fractions of it) in a couple of minutes!